# Jest test returning "function anonymous" when testing setState React hook

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm running a test with react testing library and jest that expects a react hook state (setComparisonParameters) to run with the correct data.

However, when I run the test, it says it received `[function anonymous]`. Why is this? Is it because I've written my mock function as `jest.fn()`?

Here's the test below:

```
...
const queryData = fakeQueryData();
const jobTitles = fakeJobTitles();
const comparators = fakeComparators();
let comparatorCheckboxData = fakeComparatorCheckboxData();

let comparisonParameters = {
  jobTitle: 'Accountant I',
  yearsOfService: 5,
};
const setComparisonParameters = jest.fn();
const setComparatorCheckboxData = jest.fn();
const handleSidebarSubmit = jest.fn();

  it('runs state update on jobTitle input click', async () => {
    const { container, debug } = render(
      <Sidebar
        jobTitles={jobTitles}
        queryData={queryData}
        comparisonParameters={comparisonParameters}
        setComparisonParameters={setComparisonParameters}
        comparatorCheckboxData={comparatorCheckboxData}
        setComparatorCheckboxData={setComparatorCheckboxData}
        handleSidebarSubmit={handleSidebarSubmit}
      />
    );
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('job-title-dropdown'));
    fireEvent.change(screen.getByTestId('job-title-dropdown'), {
      target: { value: 'Administrative Analyst' },
    });
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(setComparisonParameters).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        jobTitle: 'Administrative Analyst',
        yearsOfService: 0,
      });
    });
  });
```

but this test is returning:

```
 FAIL  src/tests/Sidebar.test.tsx
  ● <Sidebar/> › runs state update on jobTitle input click

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: {"jobTitle": "Administrative Analyst", "yearsOfService": 0}
    Received: [Function anonymous]

    Number of calls: 1
```

Here's how `setComparisonParameters` is being called in the `Sidebar`:

```
  function handleJobTitleDropdownChange(e: any): void {
    setComparisonParameters((prevState: ComparisonTypes) => ({
      ...prevState,
      jobTitle: e.target.value,
    }));
  }
```

Comment: How did you call `setComparisonParameters` in the `Sidebar` component? Show the code

Comment: @LinDu I've added that function to the end of the question

Comment: A complete, runnable [mcve] would be good. Lots of missing gaps here. In particular, there's no way to tell how `Sidebar` winds up calling `handleJobTitleDropdownChange` or what it renders. It's potentially concerning that all(?) of Sidebar's state getters and setters are passed in. Hopefully that wasn't done purely for testing, and those really are controlled/needed by its parent.

Comment: Hi @ggorlen, yes, those getters/setters are all needed by Sidebar's parent. I'll create a minimal reproducible example, maybe in a new question. Thanks

Comment: @ggorlen, please check out my reprex here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75212153/jest-test-returning-function-anonymous-when-testing-setstate-hook

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, [edit] this one please.

Comment: I answered the other one, so you can probably delete this one, but above comment stands as a future suggestion.